# .htaccess requests correct login twice with .htpasswd and wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I use .htaccess to ask for credentials to access members only data. The .htaccess file is stored in one of the directories and protects everything in directories below it. The .htaccess file itself is very simple:

```
AuthName "Members Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxx/data/.htpasswd

require valid-user
```

Problem is, when we moved to a new server (and built the new website within that directory using WordPress), the Authentication Box now comes up twice and requires users to enter the same correct login information both times.

I've read in other strings here about trailing `/`, but since I don't have a redirect or anything else in my .htaccess, I'm not quite sure what to do.

Anybody have any suggestions on a workaround or rewrite?

Comment: Is there a chance your host is using CPanel and the login credentials were entered as directory protection in addition to the `.htaccess` file? It sounds like the login is occurring at both the `.htaccess` level and the `httpd.conf` level.

Comment: As a matter of fact, yes, the new host is using cPanel, although I don't know about the httpd.conf.  I know that the other directories above where the .htaccess in question is work without any issue - but not below.

Any ideas how to solve the problem or what I should look into next?

Comment: If you log in to CPanel, there is a section dealing with directory protection, see if anything is configured there that could be duplicating what is in the .htaccess. Otherewise, SSH into the server and check out the httpd.conf and any related files for settings that could be duplicating the .htaccess.

Comment: Also: if you disable the login in the .htaccess... is a login still required?

Comment: Nope - if I disable the htaccess, no login is required.

And, I don't see any CPanel protection for directories.  I never set that up in cPanel, only in htaccess.  And nothing showing up in httpd.conf 

So close.....

Comment: OK, another piece of the puzzle.

In the WordPress directory which is below the aforemention .htaccess, there is another htaccess which says the following:



# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xxx/xxx/xxx/members/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xxx/xxx/xxx/members/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
\

Comment: A revised comment:

In the WordPress directory in the folder with the .htaccess, there is another htaccess which says:

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xxx/xxx/xxx/members/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /xxx/xxx/xxx/members/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

So, we've got a 2nd htaccess - this one put there by WP.  When I disable the 2nd one, the authentication box only comes up once.  Do I need this 2nd one?  Should the 2 be integrated??  Thoughts?

Comment: @Billy - we can't read your code when it's placed in a comment. Please update your question and be sure to indent your code by four spaces or select your code and click on `{}` in the toolbar.

Comment: Based on the comments above, it sounds like the 2nd dialog is being triggered by Wordpress's rewrite code in the .htaccess file. Try moving the password logic into Wordpress's .htaccess file?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely because you're running an https redirect (or another redirect) inside another .htaccess file. So it is asking for the authentication once in http, and once in https. If you do this:

```
<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Area"
    AuthUserFile "/yourdirectory/.htpasswd"
   <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      AuthMerging And
   </IfVersion>
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

then it will only ask for the password once the redirect has happened. Otherwise, get rid of the second redirect.